# When creating an Object of my Gui in another class the frame loads but nothing appears inside

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

I've made the initialize method public, didn't help and I've set visible to true both here and the external class as seen below, any help would be appreciated. I created the gui using the window builder tool from eclipse

```
GeneralWindow frame = new GeneralWindow();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
```

package gui;

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Font;

public class GeneralWindow extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GeneralWindow window = new GeneralWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GeneralWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Order");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(309, 12, 115, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Search");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(309, 46, 115, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Stock");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(309, 80, 115, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("Emplyoees");
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(309, 114, 115, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_3);

        JButton btnNewButton_4 = new JButton("Price Amend");
        btnNewButton_4.setBounds(309, 148, 115, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_4);

        JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("Total");
        btnNewButton_5.setBounds(309, 182, 115, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_5);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 228, 178, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblProductcodeBar = new JLabel("Productcode Bar");
        lblProductcodeBar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblProductcodeBar.setBounds(10, 209, 125, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblProductcodeBar);

        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
        btnEnter.setBounds(198, 227, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(10, 11, 277, 196);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your initialize() just change the frame to this keyword
e.g

```
 //Remove this line
 frame = new JFrame();
 //change frame to this keyword
 this.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

That its u r done...

Answer (score 2):

You're making the frame `frame`, of type GeneralWindow, visible. But you never add any component to that frame. Instead, your initialize method creates yet another frame, and adds many components to that frame. Don't create another frame, and add the components to `this`, instead.

Comment: could you write an example as I'm having a little difficulty understanding how to do that.

Comment: Remove `private JFrame frame;` from GeneralWindow. Then replace all the occurrences of `frame`, in GeneralWindow, by `this`. Oh, and don't use a null layout and don't set the bounds of your components. Use a layout manager, as explained in the Swing tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the two answers provide here give a correct solution, they both reinforce the view that you should extend JFrame. This is not good advice in general, as you should favour composition over inheritance. Indeed the way you were writing the code to include a JFrame as a private member was the correct instinct.

I've included a stripped down version of your code that doesn't extend `JFrame` Instead it creates an instance of the `JFrame` when you call the `createAndDisplayFrame()` method.

```
public class GeneralWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton orderButton;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GeneralWindow window = new GeneralWindow();
                window.crateAndDisplayFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public void crateAndDisplayFrame() {
        initialize();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        orderButton = new JButton("Order");
        orderButton.setBounds(309, 12, 115, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(orderButton);
    }

}
```